# angular-handsontable sizing/layout glitching when data inputted

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, handsontable

I'm building in Angular 5 and using `Handsontable` for a spreadsheet interface in some components. Handsontable is misbehaving and I cannot work out why.

My config looks something like this:

**settings.component.ts**

```
// staff and manager add Handsontable
hotOne: any = {
  data: [],
  colHeaders: [
    'Name<span style="color: var(--cbRed);">&#42;</span>',
    'Email<span style="color: var(--cbRed);">&#42;</span>',
    'Staff Type<span style="color: var(--cbRed);">&#42;</span>',
    'Activity<span style="color: var(--cbRed);">&#42;</span>',
    'Employee ID',
    'WWCC Number',
    'WWCC Issue Date'
  ],
  columns: [], // set in ngOnInit (as we need to wait for user and organisation to be set)
  colWidths: [],
  options: {
    preventOverflow: 'horizontal',
    minRows: 20,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: false,
    stretchH: 'all'
  }
};
```

**settings.component.html**

```
<div class="hot-container">
    <hot-table
      [data]="hotOne.data"
      [columns]="hotOne.columns"
      [colHeaders]="hotOne.colHeaders"
      [colWidths]="hotOne.colWidths"
      [preventOverflow]="hotOne.options.preventOverflow"
      [minRows]="hotOne.options.minRows"
      [minSpareRows]="hotOne.options.minSpareRows"
      [rowHeaders]="hotOne.options.rowHeaders"
      [stretchH]="hotOne.options.stretchH">
    </hot-table>
</div>
```

**settings.component.css**

```
.hot-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The issues appear to stem largely from the `div.wtHolder` and `div.wtHider`. Pasting 30 items into the table results in:

1. A large space being created below the table itself.
2. Only 21/30 items showing in the table (i.e. only 21 `<tr>` elements). Interestingly, if I remove `overflow: hidden` from the css file, 28/30 items will show.

**See this screenshot of the issue:**

[image]

Also, if I remove `height: 350px;` and `overflow: hidden;` from the CSS, pasting data, using the dropdown, tabbing between cells, and even opening and closing the terminal in Chrome causes the space below the table to grow and grow!?!?!

Thanks for any help in pointing me in the right direction as to solving this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all I needed to do was to set the `renderAllRows` option to `true`. This surprisingly fixed all the issues above.